# How to correctly handle two or more Javascript timers

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I am trying to call every two seconds. 
In the function I am displaying some text which after one second calls another function that hides the text for one second. It essentially flashes the picture every second on and off.

After this finishes, it runs this again for an x amount of times until a condition is met.

I am having issues with timing it correctly.

```js
const getRandomNumber = () => {
    myFunction();
    textContent = 3;
}

function myFunction() {
    updatecurrent.textContent = "";
    setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}

var myVar = setInterval(getRandomNumber, 2000 );
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using two timers for this, or I don't understand your question very well, but to do it you only needs something like this:

```js
let text = "Some Text";
let display_text = "";
let show = true;
let interval_ref;

function start(){
  show = true;
  interval_ref = setInterval(()=>{
    if(!show) {
      clearInterval(interval_ref); // stop the loop
    }
    else{
      if(display_text){
        display_text = "";
      }
      else{
        display_text = text;
      }
      document.getElementById("display-text").innerHTML = display_text;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop(){
  show = false;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="stop()">stop</button>
</div>
<p id="display-text"></p>
```